# Remove column from column control popup menu

Tags: java, swing, swingx, jxtable

Is it possible to control whether a column should be available in a **column control popup menu**? I'm aware of toggling (Disable/enable using CheckBoxList) and gray-out the column. But I do not want column entry in popup menu as The column is must-have column in Jtable. I'm using the JXTable. Anyone that have any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A TableColumnExt has a property hideable which effectly disables the hiding. It is still shown in the popup and you can toggle the checkbox ([that's a bug, just filed](https://java.net/jira/browse/SWINGX-1573) - the menu item should be disabled ;), but at least the column isn't hidden. To work around the bug, you can implement a custom column control (as Robin correctly suggested) which doesn't add the checkbox, something like:

```
JXTable table = new JXTable(new AncientSwingTeam());
// here the hideable property is configured manually, 
// in production code you'll probably have a custom ColumnFactory
// doing it based on some data state 
table.getColumnExt(0).setHideable(false);
ColumnControlButton columnControl = new ColumnControlButton(table) {

    @Override
    protected ColumnVisibilityAction createColumnVisibilityAction(
            TableColumn column) {
        if (column instanceof TableColumnExt
                && !((TableColumnExt) column).isHideable())
            return null;
        return super.createColumnVisibilityAction(column);
    }

};
table.setColumnControl(columnControl);
table.setColumnControlVisible(true);
```

As to not including the menu item: when introducing the hideable property, we decided to go for [keeping the item in the list but disable it](https://java.net/jira/browse/SWINGX-803) because users might get confused not seeing all columns in the control. So once the bug will be fixed (just done, committed as of revision #4315), I would recommend to remove the custom column control again. Just my 2 euro-cents, though :-)

Answer (score 2):

`ColumnControlButton#createColumnVisibilityAction` looks like the method you are looking for. According to the documentation:

> Creates and returns a ColumnVisibilityAction for the given TableColumn. The return value might be null, f.i. if the column should not be allowed to be toggled

you can return `null` for your case.

You should be able to plug this in by using the `JXTable#setColumnControl` method.

Answer (score 1):

First way:

```
myTable().getColumnExt(_column_number_).setHideable(false);
```

This works smooth but has one UI drawback: text in menu is gray and thick is black - bad user experience.

So try to fix it, text will be gray and thick won't be here:

```
public class MyTable extends JXTable
{
    public MyTable(AbstractTableModel model)
    {
        //first two columns won't be hiddeable
        ColumnControlButton controlButton = new ColumnControlButton(this)
        {
            @Override
            protected ColumnControlPopup createColumnControlPopup()
            {
                return (new NFColumnControlPopup());
            }

            class NFColumnControlPopup extends DefaultColumnControlPopup
            {
                @Override
                public void addVisibilityActionItems(List<? extends AbstractActionExt> actions)
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i < actions.size(); i++)
                    {
                        AbstractActionExt action = actions.get(i);
                        JCheckBoxMenuItem chk = new JCheckBoxMenuItem(action);
                        //Disabling unwanted items but they will be still shown for smooth user experience
                        if(i == 0 || i == 1)
                        {
                            chk.setEnabled(false);
                            chk.setSelected(false);
                            //chk.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Icons.class.getResource("check.png")));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            chk.setSelected(true);
                        }
                        chk.addItemListener(action);
                        super.addItem(chk);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        this.setColumnControl(controlButton);
    }
}
```

and if you need to hide controls for "show horizontal scrollbar", "pack" and "pack all" add into code:

```
//remove items for horizontal scrollbar, pack and packall
this.getActionMap().remove("column.horizontalScroll");
this.getActionMap().remove("column.packAll");
this.getActionMap().remove("column.packSelected");
```

right after calling `super(model)`

Comment: Thanks the latter 3 lines really helped me. You should use the constants though JXTable.HORIZONTALSCROLL_ACTION_COMMAND, JXTable.PACKALL_ACTION_COMMAND and JXTable.PACKSELECTED_ACTION_COMMAND